# Keep knockout select menu open when clicking on options inside

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can i prevent the select menu from closing when clicking inside, and when clicking outside the menu it should close itself

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/1jekvsb6/1/

i tried to use this reference 
https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html
that other people have pointed but i couldnt get this to work... any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

hi john In case multi select prevent closing and outside click simple remove the items
and at click event add the items . I display just multiple selection

```js
var model = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.arr = ko.observableArray([
    { Type: "Item1" },
    { Type: "Item2" },
    { Type: "Item3" },
    { Type: "Item4" },
    { Type: "Item5" }
  ])
}

var theModel = new model();
ko.applyBindings(theModel, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <select multiple style="width: 150px;" size=5 data-bind="options: arr, optionsText: 'Type', optionsValue: 'Type', click: function() {}, clickBubble: false">
    <option data-bind="click: function() {return false;}, clickBubble: true"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can ensure your stack snippet runs by pasting in the HTML and Javascript separately (just like in the linked fiddle). If you rely on a library you'll need to include a link to a CDN/online resource. I've fixed the snippet in this answer for you, but thought I'd let you know for any future answers you might post.

Comment: Yes I just change your select option multiple .Your code runs fine